# How to persist elements in the Flask g context

Tags: python, flask

I am following the factory pattern for a Flask Application: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/ however, I am not able to persist elements in the `g` context.

Here the 2nd print throws `AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'aaa'`:

```
from flask import Flask, g

...

def create_app():

    ...

    app = Flask(__name__)
    with app.app_context():
        g.aaa = "aaa!"
        print("1", g.aaa)

    with app.app_context():
        print("2", g.aaa)
```

I have also tried with a manual wrap `oe_ctx = app.app_context()` then `oe_ctx.push()`, unfortunately it does not work.

Originally that `g` code was used elsewhere in the code (after invoking `create_app()`), I've added an example of failure inside `create_app()` for simplicity.

How can I make elements survive inside the `g` proxy object to be used during the entire life of a Flask Application?

If it helps: I am running Flask inside Tornado with something like this:

```
http_server = HTTPServer(
    WSGIContainer(app),
    ...
)
http_server.listen(5000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

But I am not even reaching this part of the code, so I don't think Tornado is affecting the behaviour of Flask or `g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer your question:

- Q: How can I make elements survive inside the g proxy object to be used during the entire life of a Flask Application?
- A: **No, you can't.** because `g` persists data only *within a context*, and it is not an appropriate place to store data between requests (see [storing-data#Note](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/#storing-data) for more details.)

Instead of using `g`, you may use `app`/`current_app` to keep some value in `.config`.
here's the code:

```
from flask import Flask, g, current_app

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    with app.app_context():
        #in context, you can use current_app to fetch or assign app.config['key']
        current_app.bb = 'bbb!' # not normally used
        current_app.config['aaa'] = 'aaa!' # usually we use current_app.config['name'] = 'value'
        print("1", app.bb) # for this example, using app or current_app has no different.
        print("1", current_app.config['aaa'])

    with app.app_context():
        #here to use current_app to get what you want.
        print("2", current_app.bb)
        print("2", current_app.config['aaa'])

>>>create_app()
1 bbb!
1 aaa!
2 bbb!
2 aaa!
```

Some Notes: ([storing-data (same as above link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/)))

- `current_app` is for solving circular import problem.
- For storing data across requests, using `session` or database.

When in need to inject elements from the Flask `config` into the routes defined in some Flask blueprints:

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app

...

my_routes = Blueprint("my_routes", __name__)

...


@my_routes.route("/foo_path", methods=["POST"])
def foo_route():
    ...
    my_aaa = current_app.config["aaa"]
```

If you need to release some resources before shutting down the Flask Application (e.g. release unix sockets, TCP sockets and so on), then you can use a combination of the Flask Config/context and `atexit` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) like this:

```
import atexit

def _close_resources(app):
    with app.app_context():
        app.logger.warning("Closing resources")
        current_app.config["aaa_resource"].close()

...

def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)

    def app_close_resources():
        return _close_resources(app)

    atexit.register(app_close_resources)
    ...
```

Comment: Oh! For some reason I thought `g` would do the same as `current_app.config`. How do I access `app` inside the Blueprint routes? I need to do this: `with app.app_context()`, but in those routes I have `my_routes = Blueprint("my_routes", __name__)` and annotations like `@my_routes.route("/foo_path", methods=["POST"])`

Comment: @TPPZ [see the link like you posted](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/appfactories/), use `current_app.config` within it.

Comment: Thanks - I updated your answer above. I have to say the Flask documentation is very dry, they usually focus on basic scenarios.

Comment: @TPPZ Wow, thanks for the great updating.